# Hiding Title in a Fullscreen mode?

Tags: android, fullscreen, title

Is there a way to hide the window title so that it won't get shown in fullscreen mode (

```
getWindow().setFlags(LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
                LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN)
```

) but then will appear upon

```
getWindow().clearFlags(LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN)
```

?

```
requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE)
```

is not an option of course as this won't allow to get it back.

Comment: So you're wanting to be able to turn it on and off at will?

Comment: Yes. To be more precise, I want to show a progressbar, but that is coupled with title.

Answer (score 59, accepted):

The way I handle this in my Android games is to call the following line in the onCreate() of my Activity

```
requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
```

I can then turn the full screen capability off and on using the following code in my activity class (usually called from a menu option)  (the m_contentView variable is the view from findViewById() using the id that you used when calling setContentView() in your on create)

```
private void updateFullscreenStatus(boolean bUseFullscreen)
{   
   if(bUseFullscreen)
   {
        getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
        getWindow().clearFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FORCE_NOT_FULLSCREEN);
    }
    else
    {
        getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FORCE_NOT_FULLSCREEN);
        getWindow().clearFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
    }

    m_contentView.requestLayout();
}
```

I use this technique in all of my games without problem.

Why do you say

> requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
>   is not an option of course

?

::EDIT::

Well if you are trying to dynamically show and hide it during the lifetime of the activity I am not sure if you can do that with the official Window Title due to the note that has been mentioned about window features needing to be set before setContentView() is called ([link](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/Window.html#requestFeature(int)))

One thing that you could do is implement your own title bar and dynamically show and hide that... I put together this example that should set you o nthe right track

Here is the layout file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:fadingEdgeLength="0sp"
    >

    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/myTitleBarLayout" 
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/myTitleBarTextView"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/app_name"
            android:paddingTop="4dip"
            android:paddingBottom="4dip"
            android:paddingLeft="6dip"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:shadowColor="#BB000000"
            android:shadowRadius="3.0"
            android:shadowDy=".25"

        />

        <View
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="1dip"
            android:background="#CCEEEEEE"
            android:padding="10dip"
        />
    </LinearLayout>

    <ScrollView  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        >

        <!-- Insert your regular layout stuff here -->

        <Button android:id="@+id/toggle_title_button" 
            android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Toggle Title" 
        />
    </ScrollView>
</LinearLayout>
```

And here is the code for the main activity that will allow you to toggle our custom title bar on and off

```
package com.snctln.test.HelloGridView;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.Window;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class HelloGridView extends Activity
{
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        TextView tv = (TextView)this.findViewById(R.id.myTitleBarTextView);
        tv.setBackgroundColor(0xFF848284);
        tv.setTextColor(0xFFFFFFFF);

        Button toggleTitleButton = (Button)this.findViewById(R.id.toggle_title_button);

        toggleTitleButton.setOnClickListener( new OnClickListener()
            {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v)
                {
                    LinearLayout ll = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.myTitleBarLayout);

                    if(ll.getVisibility() == View.GONE)
                    {
                        ll.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        ll.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    }
                }
            });
    }
}
```

It doesn't look perfect, but you can always play with the layout some more to do that.

[image]

My other thought is if you just want to hide everything to show a progress bar why not use the [ProgressDialog](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ProgressDialog.html)?

This class is pretty easy to use...

```
progressDlg = ProgressDialog.show(context, getString(R.string.progress_dialog_title_prepare), getString(R.string.progress_dialog_body_prepare));

// do long running operation

if(operationFailed)
{
    progressDlg.cancel();
}
else
{
    progressDlg.dismiss();
}
```

Comment: Because I need to switch the app from fullscreen to a 'normal' mode with title at some point.

Comment: @snctln: Sorry, I didn't understand your description of the `m_contentView` variable. What I did in my oncreate was `setContentView(R.layout.birdview)`. Which would be my `m_contentView`? I tried `findViewById(R.layout.birdview).requestLayout()` but got a null  pointer exception.

Comment: @Luis A. Florit : You should search for `android.R.id.content` - it is the topmost parent of the view hierarchy (created in Activity by calling to `setContentView()` method)

Answer (score 13):

Adding `android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen"` to application tag in the manifest file will make every activity fullscreen.

Comment: Note that this also works in an individual activity's manifest tag.

Answer (score 11):

**To disable the title of your application** (it is the app name)

```
requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE)
```

**To disable the notification bar on the top** (so a request to the android app manager to allow Fullscreen)

`getWindow().addFlags(LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN)`

Hope this helps any one who wants to know the difference!!

Comment: You can also hide the navigation bar with the following kotlin code:

`window.decorView.systemUiVisibility = (
    View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LOW_PROFILE
    or View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN
    or View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE
    or View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE_STICKY
    or View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_HIDE_NAVIGATION
    or View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION
)`

Answer (score 10):

```
if(useFullscreen)  
{  
    getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);  
    getWindow().clearFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FORCE_NOT_FULLSCREEN);  
}  
else  
{  
    getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FORCE_NOT_FULLSCREEN);  
    getWindow().clearFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);  
}
```

this worked for me .. at onResume method

Comment: who voted down? if this code doesnt work i would never give it here ... you could try on your own .. worked at emulator 1.6 and 2.2 and on my Hero 2.1

Answer (score 3):

On Android 3+ it can be easilyy achieved by calling `getActionBar().hide()` and `getActionBar().show()` to respectively show and hide the standard ActionBar

On Android 1,2 the best solution (I guess) is to implement custom View for yout "title bar" and hide it on demand (of course, calling to `requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);` at the beginning).

Answer (score 1):

that is not possible according to the docs and the android-developers google group. to implement that , you need to add a 'title-bar-like' layout item with your text and progress bar and hide/show when you need it. right now - no other way around it, since title bar control can be done only before the setContentView call and not changed after.