# enunciator/notification bar conflicting with a custom view?

Tags: android, android-orientation, android-windowmanager

My Android application has to, at some point, switch to *landscape* mode with no enunciator bar to display a screen that takes up the full display hight and width.  I do this by calling

```
setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE)
```

and by calling "`setFlags`" on the Window object passing in "`WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN`"

When I return to *portrait* mode and recover the enunciator bar using `setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT)`

and setting the flag "`WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FORCE_NOT_FULLSCREEN`" and "`WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_LAYOUT_INSET_DECOR`".

My layout object's **origin (0,0)** is now *under* the enunciator.  So the first 15 or so pixels of my application view are covered over by the *enunciator/cell signal/battery bar*.

Has anyone else seen this problem?
Is there a flag that I'm missing that will recover *portrait/non-fullscreen* without pushing my application up into the top bar?

Comment: Some would call it the notification bar or the battery/cell-signal-strength bar.

Answer (score 0):

Just find a solution from this previous post [Hiding Title in a Fullscreen mode?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/991764/hiding-title-in-a-fullscreen-mode)

```
private void updateFullscreenStatus(bUseFullscreen)
{   
   if(bUseFullscreen)
   {
        getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
        getWindow().clearFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_LAYOUT_INSET_DECOR);
    }
    else
    {
        getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_LAYOUT_INSET_DECOR);
        getWindow().clearFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
    }

    m_contentView.requestLayout();
}
```