# Hiding title bar / notification bar when device is oriented to landscape

Tags: java, android, titlebar, device-orientation

I want my title bar to be hidden when I turn my device to landscape. I have seen the XML option to hide the title bar, and the following example of doing it programmatically:

```
//Remove title bar
this.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
//Remove notification bar
this.getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
```

BUT, I am using `configChanges` parameter for `orientation` and `screenSize`, so my activity is not re-created again when it is orienting to landscape (I'm doing this for some reasons). So I cannot use the above methods as these calls need to be made before `setContentView()`.

So any ideas? Thank you.

Comment: Youtube Application is doing it somehow ... and I am sure they are not creating the activity again ( try running the video in portrait. and then turn to landscape ).

Comment: I don't think you can change the decorview after you have called the setcontentview. I would suggest that you start the view in a fullscreen mode and make your titlebar part of your contentview. that way on oreientation change you can hide it.

Comment: read this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4853505/android-how-to-disable-feature-no-title, suggestion define your own title, and you can hide and show as you like.

Answer (score 19):

was searching for an answer, ended up here, put the pieces together and here they are:

```
if (getResources().getConfiguration().orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE) {
  getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
}
else {
  getWindow().clearFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
}
```

Answer (score 7):

Assuming you have defined `configChanges`for the `Activity` in the manifest then you can achieve your issue overriding `onConfigurationChanged` method:

```
@Override
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
     super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
     if(newConfig.orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE) {
          getActionBar().hide();
     } else {
          getActionBar().show();
     }
}
```

You will have to use `getSupportActionBar()` instead of `getActionBar()` if using the support library.

Comment: In AppCompatActivity it's not fired!

Answer (score 3):

first check your device orientation by using following code

**The current configuration, as used to determine which resources to retrieve etc, as available from the Resources' Configuration object as:**

```
getResources().getConfiguration().orientation
```

Then do the necessary coding related to hide title bar and notification bar.

Answer (score 0):

```
@Override
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration config) {
     super.onConfigurationChanged(config);
     if(config.orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE) {
          getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
          getActionBar().hide();
     } else {
          getWindow().clearFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
          getActionBar().show();
     }
}
```

**You can use this I have tried by my self.**

Answer (score -2):

In your "AndroidManifest.xml", in the activity tag you can specify "NoTitleBar" in the theme property so that it will always hide the title:

```
<activity
    android:name="com.my_package.MyActivity" 
    android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen"
    android:configChanges="navigation|orientation|screenLayout|layoutDirection">
```