# getDrawingCache while NoTitleBar style set for the application in Android

Tags: android, screenshot

In my manifest I specified (for an entire application) style:

```
  android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar"
```

Then in my app I want to create a screenshot of the app using drawing cache:

```
  View activityView = getActivity().getWindow().getDecorView().findViewById(android.R.id.content);
  activityView.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
  Bitmap currentScreen = Bitmap.createBitmap(activityView.getDrawingCache());
  activityView.setDrawingCacheEnabled(false);
```

Problem is that on the screenshot there is a gap on top (size of the title bar). I get the right screenshot if title bar is on, or if the app is in the fullscreen mode. I tried to use buildDrawingCache(true), but it made no difference. Any idea how can I can get a "real" screenshot in noTitleBar mode?

Answer (score 0):

Try to on/off your title bar if you can

```
/** set title bar to ON  */
activityView.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
Bitmap currentScreen = Bitmap.createBitmap(activityView.getDrawingCache());
activityView.setDrawingCacheEnabled(false);
/** set title bar to OFF  */
```

EDIT:

I haven't tried and I'm not sure if will going to work, but have you tried to make a screenshot to your main (first in xml) layout by referencing it with findViewById? Do you still have problems with the title bar?

Comment: It's a good idea for a workaround, but switching title bar on/off is troublesome (details in [this SO post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/991764/hiding-title-in-a-fullscreen-mode)). With fragments that may not even be possible. Nonetheless, thanks for your input!