# Remove top notification bar in android phone

Tags: android

In android phone we can see the top side contains icons for signal indicator, battery charge indicator, etc. When we click on any application these indicators are also visible along with our application's activity. Is there any way to remove those indicators when we run an application ???

Thank you,
Yugandhar

Comment: possible duplicate of [Hiding Title in a Fullscreen mode?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/991764/hiding-title-in-a-fullscreen-mode)

Comment: Well its sorta of different as the discussion went for how to dynamically remove and add the titlebar in the same activity and got pretty lengthy.  This one was just how to remove it with two realy good answers.  I say leave since my search only found this reference.

Answer (score 7):

Surely you can get rid of it using this line in you manifest file:

Add this line to each activity tag in manifest.

```
android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Wallpaper.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen"
(it will set your current wallpaper as background of your activity with no Titlebar shown and all your component would be mounted on the screen)
```

you can also try this:

```
android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen"
```

Comment: @yugandhar babu: if it worked for you,please accept the answer.

Comment: Why would you ever want your wallpaper to be the background of your activity app?

Comment: This works for me tested it out and its good android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen"

Answer (score 4):

Hide title programtically:

```
requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
```

Usage: In onCreate before setContentView

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);        
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    setContentView(R.layout.splash);
```

Full Screen: No status bar(use it after setContentView)

```
 getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
```