# How to prevent user from scrolling the tablet to open Settings screen programmatically Samsung Galaxy Tab 4 10.1

Tags: android

I have a Samsung Galaxy Tab 4 10.1(Android Kitkat sdk 19) and have tried to make my company app Kiosk mode. The problems I have been facing are on the following.

1. When the app started and I scroll the screen, Wifi, location, mute, and Settings show up. My boss wants me to lock this but I don't think it is possible to do it unless I ROOT the device or I would use like SureLock or ChildLock app.
2. Also, I locked the back button. There are two more buttons that I need to deal with; Home button and the button that shows the current application. Due to the security reason, I didn't lock Home button but I would launch the app when user is outside of our app. But I was not able to disable the other button that shows the current apps. This button would show the currently running apps and give user to close the app or mess things up.

Isn't there anyways I can solve my two problems?  I was trying to ROOT the device before but since then, the tablet got fried. I don't think it's the good idea to even try it..I hope I can get some helps here.. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

For the Home button you can make your application as a launcher/Home screen application. However, for the setting button you can follow JS's advise, which is:

Since the settings menu is opened via an implicit Intent I just need to add the right intent filters my activity:

```
<intent-filter >
   <action android:name="android.settings.SETTINGS" />
   <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
</intent-filter>
<intent-filter >
   <action android:name="android.settings.WIRELESS_SETTINGS" />
   <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
</intent-filter>
```

This will let the user chose the settings application he wants to open. If I now set my activity as default, the user can not access the settings menu via the status bar.

**Reference:**

[Override or disable settings menu](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8225156/override-or-disable-settings-menu)