# Set Android phone for ShowRoom

Tags: android, security

We, my company, are facing a problem. We have a phone in public use where we can't be always near the phone. It's a show room where public user can test our Android app.
The problem is :

1) Can we block the phone in our app ? we just pin it but it doesn't block the phone. We found some apps the make something like that but not good results

2) A test user just add a security password to lock the phone. So now, we can't unlock the phone. We need to forbid user to add a lock password but we don't want to add one because if the phone is sleeping, a user should be able to unlock it.
**Edit : ** We can't block user from accessing settings

So, is there a solution for that ? like a "ShowRoom" mod ?

If you need more precisions, please ask.

Thanks

Comment: Can I have your mail id?

Comment: So you want to phone to be locked or some basic feature should work?

Comment: Excactly. Idealy, the phone should be lock on our app.

Comment: You can develop an app kind of `launcher` where you can hide the app from clicking/launching. So it can become demo/showroom phone.

Comment: The answer for the second point is here : http://stackoverflow.com/a/8244131/2311451

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you need to add the following attribute to your activity:

```
        android:launchMode="singleTask"
```

Then add two categories to the intent filter :

```
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.HOME" />
```

The result could look something like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.dummy.app"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="11"
        android:targetSdkVersion="19" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name="com.dummy.app.MainActivity"
            android:launchMode="singleTask"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.HOME" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

please read this answer to block exiting app

https://stackoverflow.com/a/16333555/5223973

if you want to use any third party app to lock your app you can use any
 android parental control apps

Comment: how it locks the phone?

Comment: Ok, the phone is in transit from the showroom to our dev center, where I am. I'll try.

Comment: it will show only your app user can't go anywhere if you use your app as launcher app

Comment: Well, I just tested it in my app in debug on a device and it doesn't work. Any idea, other things to do ?

Comment: Sorry, launcher works now. But the user can set a password on the phone. Can I block this ?

Comment: Because user can deploy the status bar and access settings and set a password and can lock it and we will not be able to unlock it.

Comment: if you talk about disable powerbutton, homeButton, etc, that's not what I want. In fact, I just want to don't allow user to enter "Settings".

Comment: That's not possible dude

Comment: The answer for the second point is here : http://stackoverflow.com/a/8244131/2311451