# Hide settings app icon in dropdown menu

Tags: android, user-interface, android-settings

I need to hide a Settings app (gear) icon from Android dropdown menu (when you swipe down). Do you have any thoughts about this use case?

[image]

Comment: Why you want to hide that setting icon?

Comment: @Roadies, i develop internal company app and guys above me dont want to let other people "play" with settings.

Comment: Is that the built-in Settings icon from the Launcher ("desktop"/"home") screen?

Comment: @SamusArin yes. I use android 5.x and its a default feature

Comment: Perhaps this is a starting point https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/admin/device-admin.html

Comment: ... or here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8225156/override-or-disable-settings-menu

Comment: @SamusArin the second one is awesome. I have app settings activty so i made to open it after click on gear icon. Thanks man!

Comment: @P.Savrov Sure, np... This is good to know, so thanks to you as well :)