# Exclusive App on Android with monodroid

Tags: c#, android, xamarin.android

I'm new in Android programation and Monodroid.
I would like to know if is possible and how to make one application that exlusively run in full screen and enable to use the device only across itself.
Best regards
Piercarlo

Comment: "enable to use the device only across itself", you mean, make it inaccessible by others? You can set fullscreen mode in the manifest

Comment: @Piercarlo if my answer was sufficient, accept then answer please.

Answer (score 1):

for the full screen mode see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/991764/hiding-title-in-a-fullscreen-mode)
For the device only, i really have no clue what you mean.

Edit: you should really try to search a bit before posting question, it was really easy to find.