# Android - Make app fullscreen without title & icon?

Tags: android, fullscreen

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Hiding Title in a Fullscreen mode?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/991764/hiding-title-in-a-fullscreen-mode)

I am making a app that need to be in full screen. i want the notification bar to show, but not a titlebar or icon (my build target is 4.0.3). I have tried to put it in full screen but it stays the same.

Is there any alternative to get full screen app layout / view?

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

i want to hide the hello android text and icon

here is a example:

[image]

Comment: "I have tried to put it in full screen but it stays the same." -- what *specifically* did you try?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In the Manifest file, under each activity tab you want to be without a title bar, place:

```
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar"
```

If you wanted no notification bar as well, then use:

```
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen" >
```

Comment: what about when i change xml views, wont that make it go back to normal?

Comment: this actually worked when i put it under application

Comment: No, it wont make it go back to having the title bar as long as that theme is in the activity tabs. Yes, you can place it under the application tab for the entire application. Did this solve your answer? If so mark the answer as accepted please

Comment: is there someway I can do this without using the manifest file?